# Linear vs convex relationship: testing which one fits better

Tags: r, linear-regression, convex, best-fit-curve

I performed a Mantel regression test between two distance matrices, using residuals to control for a third variable. The Mantel test shows a significant relationship between my two variables (residualsA vs residualsB).
However, when I plot residualsA vs residualsB, it is not entirely clear whether the relationship is indeed linear or whether it is convex (U-shape).

How can I test which one (linear or convex) fits the pattern best?
I assume the convex means a quadratic function? Or exponential?

Here is a reproducible example using the iris data.

```
data(iris)
library("ggplot2") 
library("reshape2") 
library("vegan")

# distances
dist.SepL <- as.matrix(vegdist(iris$Sepal.Length))
dist.PetL <- as.matrix(vegdist(iris$Petal.Length))
dist.SepW <- as.matrix(vegdist(iris$Sepal.Width))

# A. 
# regress Sepal.Length distance against Sepal.Width distance. 
vegan::mantel(xdis=dist.SepW, ydis=dist.SepL, method="spearman", permutations=99)
#--> Mantel statistic r: 0.03639, Significance: 0.11 
# save residuals.
resA <- mantel.residuals(dist.SepL, dist.SepW)
resA.df <- as.data.frame(melt(as.matrix(resA$residuals)))  #residuals as dataframe

# B. 
# regress Petal.Length distance against Sepal.Width distance.
vegan::mantel(xdis=dist.SepW, ydis=dist.PetL, method="spearman", permutations=99)
#-->Mantel statistic r: 0.2179, Significance: 0.01 
# save residuals.
resB <- mantel.residuals(dist.PetL, dist.SepW); resB$residuals
resB.df <- as.data.frame(melt(as.matrix(resB$residuals))) #residuals as dataframe

# AB. 
# regress residual Sepal.Length distance (A.) against residual Petal.Length distance (B.)
vegan::mantel(xdis=resB$residuals, ydis=resA$residuals, method="spearman", permutations=99)
#-->Mantel statistic r: 0.6245, Significance: 0.01
# save residuals.
res.AB <- cbind(resA.df, resB.df$value) #column-bind residuals A and residuals B
colnames(res.AB) <- c("var1","var2","resA","resB") #rename variables
res.AB <- res.AB[100:200,] #subset to get a smaller df, for this example 
#(otherwise there are 22500 obs, meaning a slow calculation time and a messy plot)
```

I used geom_smooth in ggplot, to visually compare linear to loess regression lines.
Since the red SE area (linear) is smaller than the blue SE area (loess), I would say that the linear relationship fits the pattern best. Does it make sense?

```
  ggplot(res.AB, aes(y=resA, x=resB)) +
   geom_point(size=2) +
    geom_smooth(method="glm",formula = y ~ x, se=T, col="red",  fill="#fadcdd",linetype="solid") +
    geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T, col="blue", fill="lightblue", linetype="solid") +
    theme_bw() 
#red is linear
#blue is quadratic
```

[image]
But of course, this is not a proper test!
I had a look online, and this is my first attempt.

```
# linear model
mlin <- lm(resA~resB, data=res.AB)
# quadratic model
res.AB$resB2 <- res.AB$resB^2
mquad <- lm(resA~resB2, data=res.AB)

#create sequence of residual values
resvalues <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, length=64)

#create list of predicted values using the models
predictlin <- predict(mlin,list(resB=resvalues))
predictquad <- predict(mquad,list(resB=resvalues, resB2=resvalues^2))
predictlog <- predict(mlog,list(resB=resvalues))

# adjusted R-squared of each model
> summary(mlin)$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.6900567
> summary(mquad)$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.4382747
```

According to this, the linear model explains 69% of the variance, whereas quadratic model explains only 43.8%. Meaning that the linear model is better than the quadratic one.  Is that correct?
The main problem is that I used a Mantel test, and not a LM.  So, I am not sure... does this approach make sense?

In addition, the quadratic function (blue) looks quite different from the previous one.

```
#create scatterplot of original data values
plot(res.AB$resB, res.AB$resA, pch=19, cex=0.5)
#add predicted lines based on quadratic regression model
lines(resvalues, predictquad, col='blue')
lines(resvalues, predictlin, col='red')
#red is linear
#blue is quadratic
```

[image]
I had the idea of using AIC (Akaike information criterion). But GLM doesn't allow negative values (like some of my residual values). Therefore, I transformed all my residuals to positive values simply by adding a number allowing this (residuals+1).    After this transformation, I run GLM models with log and sqrt links. I don't know... how to get a quadratic GLM?

```
mlog <- glm((resA+1)~(resB+1), data=res.AB, family=poisson(link="log"))
msqrt <- glm((resA+1)~(resB+1), data=res.AB, family=poisson(link="sqrt"))
predictlog <- predict(mlog,list(resB=resvalues))

as.data.frame(AIC(mlin, mquad, mlog, msqrt))
as.data.frame(AIC(mlog, msqrt))

      df      AIC
mlin   3 -397.979
mquad  3 -337.922
mlog   2      Inf
msqrt  2      Inf
```

AIC values are:
linear: -397.979
quadratic: -337.922
logarithmic: Inf
squareroot: Inf

So, this approach is also not working.

How can I test whether a linear relatioship fits best my observed pattern than a convex relationship (or any other relationship)?

Thank you!

### EDIT:

I came up with different methods to check for the goodness-of-fit of the linear model vs. the "convex model". However, I still don't know:

1. what model (quadratic, exponential or something else) actually
   represents a convex (concave up) relationship
2. what method is the most appropriate and/or accurate

Any reply to these questions would be highly appreciated!

Here is the code (sorry for its length)... maybe it can help someone else:

```
## fit models =============================================================================================
# Fit the null model
model_null <- lm(resA ~ 1, data = res.AB)

# Fit the linear model
model_lin <- lm(resA ~ resB, data = res.AB)

# Fit the quadratic model
model_quad <- lm(resA ~ resB + I(resB^2), data = res.AB)
model_quad <- lm(resA~poly(resB, degree = 2), data=res.AB) #idem
quad_model <- nls(resA ~ a * resB^2 + b * resB + c, data = res.AB, start = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)) #with nls

# Fit the cubic model
model_cub <- lm(resA ~ resB + I(resB^3), data = res.AB)
cubic_model <- nls(resA ~ a + b*resB + c*resB^2 + d*resB^3,data = res.AB, #with nls
                   start = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1))

# Fit an exponential model (intercept at zero)
exp_model <- nls(resA ~ a * exp(b * resB), data = res.AB, start = list(a = 1, b = 0.01)) #with nls

# Fit an exponential model (random intercept)
res.AB$id <- seq(1, 64, length=64)
exp_model <- nls(resA ~ exp(a + b * resB), #with nls
                 data = res.AB,
                 start = list(a = rnorm(1), b = rnorm(1)),
                 trace = TRUE)

# create a list of these models
model.list <- list(null = model_null, linear = model_lin, quadratic = model_quad, quadratic.nls=quad_model,
                   cubic=model_cub, exponential=exp_model)
lapply(model.list, summary)

# List of residuals
resid(model_lin)

# density plot
plot(density(resid(model_lin))) #unsure how to interpret that

hist(model_lin$residuals, main="Histogram of Residuals", xlab = "bf residuals")

## residual plot  =============================================================================================
# points  randomly scattered around x=0 -> appropriate model
# curved pattern -> LM captures the trend of some data points better than that of others -> consider another model (not linear model) 
plot(res.AB$resB, model_lin$residuals, 
     ylab = "linear model residuals", xlab="independent variable"); abline(h=0, col="black", lwd=1, lty=2) 

## visual plot =============================================================================================
#create sequence of residual values
resvalues <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, length=64)

#create list of predicted values using the models
predictlin <- predict(model_lin,list(resB=resvalues))
res.AB$resB2 <- res.AB$resB^2
predictquad <- predict(model_quad,list(resB=resvalues, resB2=resvalues^2))
res.AB$resB3 <- res.AB$resB^3
predictcub <- predict(model_cub,list(resB=resvalues, resB4=resvalues^4))
res.AB$resBexp <- exp(res.AB$resB)
predictexp <- predict(exp_model,list(resB=resvalues, resBexp=exp(resvalues)))

#create scatterplot of original data values
plot(res.AB$resB, res.AB$resA, pch=19, cex=0.9)
#add predicted lines based on quadratic regression model
lines(resvalues, predictquad, col='blue')
lines(resvalues, predictlin, col='red')
lines(resvalues, predictcub, col='darkgreen')
lines(resvalues, predictexp, col='orange')

## residuals vs fitted plot (1st plot of the sequence)
plot(model_lin)
plot(model_quad)
plot(model_cub)
plot(exp_model)

## R-squared  =============================================================================================
# higher R-squared value indicates a better fit
sapply(model.list,
       function(x) {
         summary(x)$r.squared })

## AIC  =============================================================================================
# lower AIC value indicates a better model fit.
sapply(model.list, AIC)
as.data.frame(AIC(model_null, model_lin, model_quad)) #idem

## MAE  =============================================================================================
# lower MAE value indicates a better model fit.
sapply(model.list, function(x) mean(abs(x$residuals)))

## MSE  =============================================================================================
# lower MSE value indicates a better model fit.
sapply(model.list, function(model) {
  residuals <- residuals(model)
  mean(residuals^2)})

## ANOVA =============================================================================================
# smaller RSS indicates a better fit ??
# if  p-value <0.05, we can reject the null hypothesis that linear model is a better fit 
anova(model_lin, model_quad)

## Ramsey RESET test  =============================================================================================
# this test does not assumes that the quadratic model is nested within the linear model
library("car")
linearHypothesis(model_quad, c("I(resB^2) = 0"), test = "F")

anova_result <- sapply(model.list, anova)
print(anova_result)

## stepAIC  =============================================================================================
# Fit all possible models with up to quadratic terms
all_models <- lm(resA ~ I(resB^2), data = res.AB)

# Use stepAIC to perform model selection and find the best-fitting model
best_model <- MASS::stepAIC(all_models, direction = "both")

# Print the summary of the best-fitting model
summary(best_model)

## Pearson =============================================================================================
#Pearson's chi-squared test for goodness of fit.

# Calculate the expected values
expected <- predict(model_lin)

# Divide the data into 10 groups
res.AB$group <- cut(expected, breaks = 10)

# Calculate the observed frequencies in each group
observed <- table(res.AB$group, res.AB$resA > 0)

# Perform the Pearson's chi-squared test for goodness of fit
chisq.test(observed)
```

Comment: If you need advice about choosing a statistical model for your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. These are statistics questions.

Comment: Your quadratic model is missing the linear term. It should be `lm(resA~poly(resB, degree = 2), data=res.AB)`. However, I don't understand why you assume a quadratic relationship. Are you trying to implement the [Ramsey RESET test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_RESET_test)? I would just fit a GAM and look at the edf of the smoother and compare with the linear model (using `anova`).

Comment: @Roland Thank you for the correction. Now the quadratic line looks more similar to the one in the other plot.  In my actual df (and somehow in the example df) the alternative to the linear relationship is a convex relationship. I use a quadratic relationship because this is the only function resulting more or less into a convex shape that I am able to handle in R. What relationship/function would you suggest for a convex pattern? I am not familiar with GAM (only with GLM)... Do you have any tutorial/resource to suggest?